# Jenkins: How can I see which plugin is causing dependency error?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to install all the dependencies of the pipeline plugin in Jenkins. I am stuck on the workflow-scm plugin. If I enable it I get the error below which I assume is a dependency problem. All it dependencies are installed but some versions vary. I would like to see which plugin is causing the problem rather than upgrade all it dependencies hoping that it will fix the problem. The error does not give any clue on that. Is there a log file I can look at?

These are the installed dependencies versions:

```
workflow-cps dependencies:
script-security (version:1.21)          OK (1.22 installed)
workflow-scm-step (version:1.15)        OK (2.2 installed)
ace-editor (version:1.0.1)              OK (1.1 installed)
workflow-support (version:2.1)          OK (2.2 installed)
workflow-step-api (version:2.3)         OK (2.3 installed)
scm-api (version:1.1)                   OK (1.1 installed)
support-core (version:2.32, optional)   OK (2.32 installed)
structs (version:1.3)                   OK (1.2 installed)
workflow-api (version:2.1)              OK (2.1 installed)
jquery-detached (version:1.2.1)         OK (1.2.1 installed)
```

Error:

```
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:244)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:45)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1010)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:878)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:227)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at hudson.PluginManager.resolveDependantPlugins(PluginManager.java:882)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$2.run(PluginManager.java:563)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:999)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, **there is no additional logfiles**.

You could try **starting over from scratch**:

1. shutdown Jenkins
2. remove all `*workflow*` and `*pipeline*` files/directories in `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins`
3. put plugin installation files (`.hpi`) for all workflow/pipeline plugins to the `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins` folder
4. start Jenkins

Instead of step 3, you could use the plugin manager GUI -- but I guess this is what you tried in the first place.

Comment: Actually there was a jenkins /var/log/ which helped, but I think you assumed I knew that. I did a face-palm when I remembered to look there. As you advise I removed all plugins and added back until it stopped - that's how I got to workflow-cps. After that the jenkins log showed me I had a wrong version struct.